sstableloader duplicating data across replicas
I have a 3-node Cassandra cluster with a replication factor (RF) of 2 (both source and target clusters). I used sstableloader to load a snapshot backup into the target cluster. The data was loaded successfully, but I noticed that the size of the data in the target cluster is nearly double the original size.
I was expecting the data size to be similar to the source, given the same replication factor and node count.
Any insights into why this is happening and how to fix it?
For context:
I plan to load 1TB of data from the source cluster to a different target cluster, both of which are configured in Kubernetes.
Thanks in advance for your help!

The sstableloader utility streams parts of SSTables to the target nodes of a cluster. A receiving node (replica) may not necessarily own all the partitions in a given SSTable so it gets split into "chunks" so that the SSTable chunks contains mostly partitions that are in the token ranges owned by the node.
But sometimes, the SSTable chunks end up with partitions that don't necessarily belong to a node simply because it fell within the range of the tokens owned by that node. For example, a node might own token ranges [1..10, 21..30, 51..60, 71..80] but the SSTable chunk that is streamed to the node contains partitions that fall within the range [5..60]. The partitions which don't belong to the node will eventually get compacted out in the background since they don't belong to the node.
This is otherwise known as "over-streaming" and would account for the bloated size of files on disk but it will eventually resolve itself so it isn't something to worry about.
Most assume that sstableloader reads the contents of the SSTables and loads one partition at a time but this isn't true. It loads chunks of SSTables, not individual partitions. Cheers!

Ok, thanks, so after loading using sstableloader, the double size data is not an issue, it will fixed automatically when compaction run.
